# Use dictionary for Python argparse

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

I have a dictionary which maps human readable values to three different Python specific values. How can the argparse Python module use this dictionary to get me the specific values while the user can choice between the keys.

Currently I have this:

```
def parse(a):
    values = { "on": True, "off": False, "switch": None }
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--value", choices=values, default=None)
    args = parser.parse_args(a)
    print("{}: {}".format(type(args.value), args.value))

>>> parse(['-v', 'on'])
<type 'str'>: on
>>> parse(['-v', 'off'])
<type 'str'>: off
>>> parse(['-v', 'switch'])
<type 'str'>: switch
>>> parse([])
<type 'NoneType'>: None
```

The problem is, that argparse doesn't return `True`, `False` or `None` if the parameter is given. Is there an easy way to add this feature? Of course I would be able to execute something like this afterwards:

```
args.value = values[args.value]
```

This is actually what I'm doing currently, but this doesn't work well with the default value (I would have to check if the value is already None or set the default to `"switch"`). And as I'm using this multiple times I would have to do that every time.

Comment: Specifying `type=values.__getitem__` would do it. Dunno if that's a good solution, though; I am quite sleep-deprived at the moment, so I can't tell whether I'm having good ideas.

Comment: Is there a problem with setting `default='switch'?  Specifying the default choice upfront is good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest change would be to use

```
args.value = values.get(args.values)
```

so you would get None for any entry not in the dict (eg default).

Another option is to misuse the type keyword of argparse:

```
values = { "on": True, "off": False, "switch": None }
def convertvalues(value):
    return values.get(value)
parser.add_argument('-v','--value',type=convertvalues)
```

The "type" approach breaks the use of choices as used above, since choices is applied after the conversion. One possibility to preserve your use of choices would be:

```
def convertvalues(value):
     return values.get(value,value)
parser.add_argument('-v','--value',type=convertvalues,
                                   choices=[True,False,None],
                                   default=None)
```

In this case convertvalues returns the right values if 'on','off','switch' and None are used and returns the given values if something else was given (eg. 'bla'). Since 'bla' is not in choices, you get the expected error message.

Using "action" with a class derived from argparse.Action instead of type should do the job the smart way, as given in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#action):

```
class DictAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        value_dict = { "on": True, "off": False, "switch": None }
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, value_dict.get(values))
parser.add_argument('-v','--value',action=DictAction,
                                   choices=['on','off','switch'],
                                   default=None)
```

Of course this is not perfect, a better solution would overwrite the Acion **init** to get the dictionary and leave out the hardcoded value_dict.

Comment: I guess the `type` parameter should be set to `convertvalues`?

Comment: Okay when I use `type` it tells me in parseargs: “argument -v/--value: invalid choice: False (choose from 'on', 'switch', 'off')”

Comment: Of course, it needs to be convertvalues, sorry for typo. For your second comments, I believe you left choices in. Choices does the comparison after conversion, hence you would need to do choices=values.values(). However, since you get None from get for any input, this approach breaks choices. I will update the answer a bit for choices.

Comment: But this will affect how the choices are shown in the help text. Currently it is `usage: [-h] [-v {on,switch,off}]`. It appears I have to manually translate the value afterwards :(

Comment: While this custom Action approach is nice, all it ends up doing is applying the `get` at a different time and place.

Comment: I was looking for a solution where I don't have manually fix the resulting value. As it appears I actually have to do it, so I was trying to do it within itself so whenever I was using this dictionary as a parameter I can simply say use this dictionary and convert it for me. The `Action` solution appears to be the best match for that (although implementing `__init__` is cumbersome).

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't comment on oekopez' answer,
but this change would be make the class available to be used for any dictionary passed to the add_argument action.

```
class DictAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.choices.get(values, self.default))

value_dict = { "on": True, "off": False, "switch": None }
parser.add_argument('-v','--value',action=DictAction,
                               choices=value_dict,
                               default=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
values = { "on": True, "off": False, "switch": None }
parser.add_argument("-v", "--value", choices=values.keys())
value = values.get(args.value)
```

Comment: `argparse` automatically checks against the dictionary keys.