# Python argParse change string to a different type

Tags: python, parsing

I am asking user to input a string before running my python program.

```
ASK = 'ASK'
BID = 'BID'
parser.add_argument('-s', "--side", dest = 'side', help = "side", nargs = 1, 
    required = True, choices = ['ASK','BID'])
side = args.side[0] 
print side
>>"ASK"
```

I want to assign `side` to `ASK` or `BID` variables
I know I can do it this way:

```
if side == 'ASK':
    side = ASK
else: 
    side = BID
```

I was wondering if I can change `args.side[0]` to a specific variable ASK or BID within parser.add_argument.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Python 3.4+ `enum.Enum`?

Comment: Its not a python 3.4 enum. The python code is binded to C++, so it's a C++ enum.

Comment: then can you please add the `enum` declaration that you're using.

Comment: The generic thing to do would be to make a dictionary of the enum names -> values, and use the approaches from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635675/use-dictionary-for-python-argparse

Comment: Ok I changed it up a bit, I hope it makes more sense.