# Using Argparse for Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

I want to read any one of the items from a list of videos. The video reading and display code is the following. This code is working perfectly fine.

```
import cv2


def VideoReading(vid):

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Since I've large number of videos and I'm calling the code through command line, writing the entire video name is cumbersome. So I created a dictionary. Here given the example of 2:

```
{"Video1.mp4": 1, 'Video2.mp4': 2}
```

Now I'm using the following code to call the video using value 1 or 2, rather than Video name. The code is the following:

```
def Main():

    VideoFiles= ["Video1.mp4", "Video2.mp4"]
    VideoFilesIndicator = [1, 2]

    model_list = {}
    for i in range(len(VideoFiles)):
        model_list[VideoFiles[i]] = VideoFilesIndicator[i]

    print(model_list)
    def convertvalues(value):
        return model_list.get(value, value)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()


    group.add_argument("-v", "--video", help = "add video file name of any format", type = convertvalues,\
                     choices = [1,2], default = 1)

    args =parser.parse_args()

    return VideoReading(args.video)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    Main()
```

Now when I'm running the code in cmd `"python VideoReading.py -v 2"`, it's throwing me the following error.

> error: argument -v/--video: invalid choice: '2' (choose from 1, 2)

I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error. I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635675/use-dictionary-for-python-argparse) post to build my program.

Comment: The error is thrown in VideoReading(args.video)? If so, can you try to adapt it to return VideoReading(int(args.video))?

Comment: @Uvar: I already tried that. But still getting the same issue.

Comment: `model_list = dict(zip(VideoFilesIndicator, VideoFiles))`; note your dictionary is currently backwards; you want to map a number to a file name, not vice versa.

Comment: Forcing the user of the program to know the internal numbering of the files is bad interface design, though.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for your suggestions. I know, but my manager suggested me to do so!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary is backwards; you want to map a number to a file name, so that when you enter a number, a file name can be returned. There's no need to provide a default value from `convertvalues`, because you are using `choices` to limit the allowable inputs to the valid keys of the dict.

```
def main():

    video_files = ["Video1.mp4", "Video2.mp4"]

    model_list = dict(enumerate(video_files, start=1))

    print(model_list)


    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

    group.add_argument("-v", "--video", 
                       help="add video file name of any format",
                       type=lambda str: model_list[int(str)],
                       choices=model_list.values())

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return VideoReading(args.video)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But now I'm getting Typeerror for this code: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'.

Comment: Not sure how `argparse` actually comes up with that error, but I've made a few fixes that (incidentally?) removes it.

Comment: THanks for your answer. But I tried flevinkelming options and it solved my problem. But I your suggestion to create dictionary using enumerate is pretty useful to me.

Comment: I like flevinkelming's approach of converting the number to a file name after, instead of during, argument parsing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `convertvalues` is returning `'2'` as a string, because `convertvalues` returns `value` as it is (i.e. a string) when it is not found in `model_list`. Try with:

```
def convertvalues(value):
    return model_list.get(value, int(value))
```

Also, as it is, your argument parser will always receive an integer in `video` in the end (either you passed an integer or `convertvalues` transformed a video file name into an integer). To get the actual file name again you can do something like

```
args = parser.parse_args()
video_file = VideoFiles[VideoFilesIndicator.index(args.video)]
return VideoReading(video_file)
```

My suggestion is based on trying to make the minimal amount of changes to the code. However, you may also consider more changes in the program, [like flevinkelming suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45373734/1782792), if you don't feel comfortable with the final shape of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried it, but now getting the following error: 'cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:312: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow'. One gets this error when "cv2" (image reading package) don't get the frame to process. So basically it's not getting the video file name. I need to pass the video file name, rather than the value of the dictionary.

Comment: @jdhesa: I tried your answer, but I'm getting VideoFiles error. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, with minimal code, and dynamic `help` output for users:

```
import argparse

def main():

    model = {
        1: "Video1.mp4",
        2: "Video2.mp4",
        3: "Video3.mp4"
    }  # Add more if needed

    videos = ['{}({})'.format(v, str(k)) for k, v in model.items()]
    help_ = "Videos to choose from: {}".format(', '.join(videos))

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--video', help=help_, type=int, default=1)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return VideoReading(model[args.video])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`python VideoReading.py -h`:

```
usage: VideoReading.py [-h] [-v VIDEO]

optional arguments:
    -h, --help  show this help message and exit
    -v VIDEO, --v VIDEO
                      Videos to choose from: Video1.mp4(1), Video2.mp4(2),
                      Video3.mp4(3)
```

`python VideoReading.py`:

If you were printing the selection - `Video1.mp4`

`python VideoReading.py -v 3`:

If you were printing the selection - `Video3.mp4`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not only solved my problem, but you have beautifully explained it. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help!